# How do I use multiple custom test runners in Android?

Tags: android, junit, android-testing, dagger-2

I am overriding Dagger 2 Components to mock dependencies in Android. For this I am using custom JUnit TestRunners.

It seems in my `app/build.gradle` I can set only one testRunner.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.xxx.xxx'
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0.0'

    testInstrumentationRunner 'com.xxx.xxx.DgMockTestRunner'
}
```

How can I set multiple test runners? I would like every test class I write to have a separate TestRunner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`@RunWith`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/RunWith.html) annotation in your test classes to specify the test runner class:

```
@RunWith(FooTestRunner.class)
public class TestFoo {
    @Before
    public void setUp();
}
```

However, in general you can probably accomplish what you want to do using [JUnit rules](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Rules). For example, the following [DaggerMock](https://github.com/fabioCollini/DaggerMock) rule instantiates a new `MyComponent` with a `MyModule` and sets this as the root component in the application:

```
@Rule public DaggerMockRule<MyComponent> daggerRule = new DaggerMockRule<>(MyComponent.class, new MyModule())
        .set(new DaggerMockRule.ComponentSetter<MyComponent>() {
            @Override public void setComponent(MyComponent component) {
                App app = (App) InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
                app.setComponent(component);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I've tried this but I get `:KClass<out Runner!>` do I have to do something else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67163964/how-to-combine-different-testinstrumentationrunner