# How to combine different testInstrumentationRunner

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, android-espresso

Is there any way to have different testInstrumentationRunner for each test? Do I have to create a `Task` for it? I have my runner as follows :

```
class MyTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {
    override fun newApplication(
        cl: ClassLoader?,
        className: String?,
        context: Context?
    ): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, MyTestApp::class.java.name, context)
    }
}
```

But what if I want to run some using the real app? how can I choose it?

I've been reading that is possible doing it with
`@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner::class)`on my tests I'm using it but I understand if I do this it takes the one of the defaultConfig

```
defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner("mypackage.MyTestRunner")
}
```

But I can not use something like it says `Required:KClass<out Runner!>`

```
@RunWith(MyTestRunner::class)
```

In case I could do this I'd understand how can I use different runners.

Comment: In Kotlin the error message would be the expected output for `@RunWith(MyTestRunner::class.java)` - as it demands `KClass<out Runner!>`. `MyTestRunner` is `AndroidJUnitRunner`, but `KClass` is imparative.

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend [`androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/ext/junit/runners/AndroidJUnit4):

```
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4

class MyTestRunner : AndroidJUnit4() {
    ...
}
```

The dependency to use:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.test.ext
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2"
```

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner) suggests it as the default runner, therefore Kotlin interoperability should be given. Only `KClass<out Runner!>` is being accepted by the `@RunWith` annotation in a `.kt` file.

Comment: this doesn't work. AndroidJunit4 is final and cannot be extended.